# Bitbucket Pipelines hangs when testing a Nuxt app with Cypress

Tags: yaml, nuxt.js, bitbucket, cypress, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Nuxt app that I want to test with Cypress in CI.
I've seen in the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Boot-your-server) that you have to install some third-party package to wait for the server to start and then run your tests.
I then installed the [wait-on](https://github.com/jeffbski/wait-on) package and created these scripts in package.json.

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
  "start:wait": "yarn start & wait-on http://localhost:3000",
  "run:cypress": "cypress run"  
},
```

For the CI, I install the dependencies, run `nuxt generate` to bundle the app and then test using the step below.

*bitbucket-pipelines.yml*

```
- step: &e2e-test
    image: cypress/included:9.4.1
    name: Run application E2E tests
    caches:
      - cypress
    script:
      - yarn start:wait
      - yarn record:cypress -- --config video=true --parallel --ci-build-id $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
    artifacts:
      # store any generates images and videos as artifacts
      - cypress/screenshots/**
      - cypress/videos/**

# A little bit below
- parallel:
    - step: *e2e-test
    - step: *e2e-test
    - step: *e2e-test
```

It works when I test it locally but in CI, Bitbucket hangs and nothing happens.

[image]

I've also seen the [start-server-and-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test#readme) package but I don't know how to pass extra arguments like (`--config video=true --parallel --ci-build-id $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`) to `run:cypress` from the CI.

`"ci": "start-server-and-test 'yarn start' http://localhost:3000 'run-cypress <extra-arguments-here?>'"`

Like this but with arguments from the CI to retrieve `$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`

Answer (score 0):

follow these examples:
[official cypress doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/bitbucket-pipelines#Using-the-Cypress-Dashboard-with-Bitbucket-Pipelines)

[bitbucket yml example for Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/bitbucket-pipelines.yml)

I suppose you didn't provide in the script

```
yarn install
```

or

```
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

and main script

```
yarn start-server-and-test start [<http://localhost:3000>](<http://localhost:2020/>) cypress run --record --key PRODUCT_KEY --parallel --ci-build-id $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

Where `PRODUCT_KEY` is your key from Cypress Dashboard. and Rewrite parallel part as in the example above.

Comment: I switched to start-server-and-test without the `CI_BUILD_ID` and it worked :)

Comment: It is weird that works without ci_build_id but cool that finally works :)

Comment: It has a default value set for each CI provider from what I understood, and specifying it only overrides defaults https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization#Linking-CI-machines-for-parallelization-or-grouping

Comment: Yeap, but for BitBucket it required ci_build_id, in my case i am using it